# Why is there memory leak while using shared_ptr as a function parameter?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I read a manual saying that (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared):

> Moreover, `f(shared_ptr<int>(new int(42)), g())` can lead to memory leak
>   if g throws an exception. This problem doesn't exist if make_shared is
>   used.

Why would that lead to memory leak?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The compiler is allowed to evaluate that expression in the following order:

```
auto __temp1 = new int(42);
auto __temp2 = g();
auto __temp3 = shared_ptr<int>(__temp1);
f(__temp3, __temp2);
```

You can see that if `g()` throws, then the allocated object is never deleted.

Using `make_shared`, nothing can come between allocating the object and initialising the smart pointer to manage it.

Comment: +1. Yes,that is the reason, I was about to write that, but I talked about the constructor first and it got messed up.